# How to use localStroge in word Add-in

Tags: internet-explorer, ms-word, office-js, word-addins, javascript-api-for-office

I am developing a add-in using word javascript Api and i need to store some information locally so want to use the Local Storage but tried to strore the values it shows me below error:

```
Code: localStorage.setItem('favoriteflavor','vanilla');
Error: An internal error occurred in the Microsoft Internet extensions.
```

Comment: Be aware of the fact that on Mac it is only stored [until the add-in closes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38716476/add-in-persistent-settings-in-osx-mac), atleast it was so the last time i checked which is quite some time ago. 
Don't know what is wrong with your code though.

Comment: why do you want to use localStorage.. you know there is a settings object you can use to store settings on Office.js, right?

Comment: @JuanBalmori I want to store some user credentials on client side, currently i am trying to using cookies for that. Please advise.Thanks.